# Call controller function from button inside view?

Tags: laravel-5

I want to call a controller function when i click a button but the problem is when i enter the page where the button is the function that im testing runs without clicking the button and i dont know why.

Here is my button.

```
<button  href="{{action('PlantillaImagenesController@testboi')}}"  style="width:27%" class="p-2 btn btn-primary btn-lg">Guardar</button>
```

The function that im testing.

```
 public function testboi(){
        echo "Funcion controller";
    }
```

My route.

```
Route::get('/Imagen',  'PlantillaImagenesController@testboi');
```

Answer (score 1):

Make this change to your button:

```
<a href="{{ url('Imagen') }}" style="width:27%" class="p-2 btn btn-primary btn-lg">Guardar</a>
```

your button URL should match with the route name,
this is how you call a route in laravel.

You can also name your route like this:

```
Route::get('imagen', 'PlantillaImagenesController@testboi')->name('imagen');
```

And use it like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('imagen') }}" style="width:27%" class="p-2 btn btn-primary btn-lg">Guardar</a>
```

Comment: Hi i changed like you said but now it shows this error:  ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Route [admin.Imagen.index] not defined. (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ConfiguradorIEM/resources/views/home.blade.php)

Comment: i just want to know a way to call a function from my view